# Three.js Generate color on 10 random objects

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to make a function that will change `material` color for randomly choosen 10 objects, but I don't know how to "connect" it into either array or vectors. I've tried putting into `color(selector)` some of arrays like `meshArrayX` but then, the positions of objects are undefined and won't color any of object at all.

```js
var mesh, scene,
    MeshBasicMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      color: 0x000000,
      opacity: 0.3,
      transparent: true
    });
var BoxGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(16, 16, 16);

function random(){
        var random = [0, 16, 32];
        var randomValue = random[Math.floor(random.length * Math.random())];
        console.log(randomValue);
}

function color(selector){
  for(var v=0; v<10; v++){
    selector.position.x = random();
    selector.position.y = random();
    selector.position.z = random();
    selector.material.color.setHex( 0x0000ff);
  }
}

var meshArrayX = [];
for (var x=0; x<3; x++) {
  var meshArrayY = [meshArrayX.push(mesh = new THREE.Mesh(BoxGeometry, MeshBasicMaterial))];
  for(var y=0; y<3; y++){
    var meshArrayZ = [meshArrayY.push(mesh = new THREE.Mesh(BoxGeometry, MeshBasicMaterial))];
    for(var z=0; z<3; z++){
      meshArrayZ.push(mesh = new THREE.Mesh(BoxGeometry, MeshBasicMaterial));
      mesh.position.x = 16*x;
      mesh.position.y = 16*y;
      mesh.position.z = 16*z;
      scene.add(mesh);


      console.log(meshArrayX.length, meshArrayY.length-1, meshArrayZ.length-1, mesh.position);
    }
  }
}
color(mesh);
```

Comment: Your random() function is not returning any value, so you will get 'undefined' in position.x / y / z

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood what you asked, but I try to help you.

I think that you want to create an array of 27 box (3x3x3) but I dont understand your code..., you use a global variable mesh, but add to scene only in the z loop.

My code fot this operation is:

```
var BoxGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(5, 5, 5);
var meshArray = [];
for (var x=0; x<3; x++) {
  for(var y=0; y<3; y++){
    for(var z=0; z<3; z++){
      var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(BoxGeometry, material.clone());
      meshArray.push(mesh);
      mesh.position.x = 16*x;
      mesh.position.y = 16*y;
      mesh.position.z = 16*z;
      scene.add(mesh);  
      console.log(meshArray.length, mesh.position);
    }
  }
}
```

notice the "material.clone()" is necessary to create new instance of material for each mesh.

And your color function can be like this:

```
function color(selector){
  for(var v=0; v<10; v++){
   var pos= Math.floor((Math.random() * selector.length));

    selector[pos].material.color.setHex( 0x0000ff );
  }
}
```

called by:

```
color(meshArray);
```

Now, when you call the color function you select 10 random box from the array and apply the color.

I hope it can be useful

Comment: Indeed, thats what i was looking for! I've just started learning Three.jsand its quite hard to find something up-to-date. `material.clone()` was something i was searching for to make this material seperate. Thank you very much!